# Facebook likebox - css issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am having issue with the facebook like box. The stream isn't displayed correctly. So i wonder if there is a way so that i can customize the the css. I just need to add `float:left` to a div and it will all be working but i am not getting a way to do this.

If anyone can guide me so that i can have the desired result, that would be awesome.

You can check the current look of the like box [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2fba8/). If you just scroll down you can see the texts are not displayed correctly.

I tried to design with js and css too but couldn't get it to work.

[image: Broken stream]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text on the right to display properly, you simply need to change the width from 395 to about 480. Or, are you trying to have the text on the right display below the image? You won't be able to handle that unless you are able to manipulate the source of the iframe -- or use JS after the iframe is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, But i can't change the width as it comes on the sidebar of my site. So i just need another way.